# How do I safely flash a new rom on an infected android phone?

Tags: security, malware

Is using a live cd a good idea? Will it keep the rest of my computer including storage and installed OS safe?

Comment: Flashing ROM on an Android phone doesn't necessarily need a PC. What have you tried so far or how do you plan to flash new ROM? What kind of infections do you have on Android phone?

Comment: A live CD has access to all HDDs on your PC unless they are encrypted. Therefore a live CD has only a security benefit if your HDDs are encrypted or if you disconnect  them (e.g. the SATA cable) prior to booting the live CD.

Comment: It seems you are having a hard time here. I recommend you acquaint yourself with the functioning and rules of this website. [help] is a good place to start. I'd like you to note that posting duplicates is not okay. Unlike forums, our site permits the original poster to edit their post to fix mistakes or add information to make it more clear. Since this was a duplicate, I marked it as a duplicate. What you can do is, read the help centre, then go back to your original question and reduce its scope. This is a win-win for everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you should further tighten the security up more, my suggestions are:

1. Get into Safe Mode (if you are using Windows OS)
2. Fire up VM software, and do the process in there

The best is do it on Linux OS. Even though imho the malwares from phones are different from the PC ones.

Comment: Flashing from within a VM via USB is theoretically possible by redirecting the device into the VM, but based on my experience USB forwarding is usually not that stable enough for flashing.

Answer (score 0):

## You are right to be cautious.

Android malware cannot directly run on a Windows PC. Android malware CAN be used as a dropper for Windows malware, however, and this is why you should be careful about hooking up your phone. But there is one method of restore that should be safe:

## Fastboot

Boot your phone into Fastboot mode (sometimes called 'bootloader' mode) and use the fastboot command on your PC to either:

a) Flash your new image directly (usually only works for OEM images)

b) Flash or tempboot TWRP and use that to wipe your phone COMPLETELY (remove /system, /data, cache, Dalvik cache, the works) and transfer and install your new image. (usually works for custom ROMs). You can use ADB safely here as well.

Even root-access malware cannot mess with fastboot, and by extension a booted-from-fastboot recovery partition, so you should be safe restoring your phone like this.